# VM Placement with FF, BF and WF Algorithms

Tags: c

Please I am working on VM Placement using First-fit (FF), Best-fit (BF) and Worst-fit (WF) algorithms. The FF and WF seem to work pretty good but there's is a little bit of issue with the BF. The VM sequence are generated randomly for the placement.

The problem is that, sometimes when it sorts out the PMs and picks the one with the least capacity of resources and when it gets to checking if it has enough resource for hosting that particular VM it says "WAIT" instead of placing it on the next available PM with enough resources. It works well from the start but as the process continues it tends to get such error in the placements.

For example, a VM sequence of `X, S, M, L, S, L, X, L, M, M` the placement is supposed to be:

```
X  2
S  2
M  2
L  1
S  1
L  1
X  1
L  1
M  WAIT
M  WAIT
```

instead it displays:

```
X  2
S  2
M  2
L  1
S  1
L  1
X  WAIT
L  WAIT
M  WAIT
M  WAIT
```

I really don't know which part of the code is making such an error occur. I would be glad if assistance can be provided. Below is the code - thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define max 250
#define min 10

int main()
{
    int i, k,g, c[max]  = {0}, r[max]  = {0}, d[max] = {0}, cv[max] = {0},
        rv[max] = {0}, dv[max] = {0}, rw[max] = {0};  //declaration of variables

    int nf=10; char ch;

    float avgpwr=0;  //, nb = 3

    int m=2;

    int b = 1; int ff[10] = {0};

    int cm[max] = {0}, rm[max] = {0}, dm[max] = {0};

    int a;
    for (a=1; a<=b; a++)
    {
        printf("\n\tVirtual Machine Placement");
        printf("\n\t**************************************"); printf("\n");

        int flag, j, count=0;

        char vm_type[] = {'S', 'M', 'L', 'X'};

        printf("\n");


        //loop throug array and print values

        for (i=1; i<=nf; i++)
        {
            //generate random index number
            int index = my_rand ();

            printf("VM %d:",i); printf("%-5c", vm_type[index]);

            switch(vm_type[index]) {

            case 'S':
                cv[i]= 2; rv[i]= 4; dv[i]= 50;  rw[i] = 69;

                break;

            case 'M':
                cv[i]= 3; rv[i]= 8; dv[i]= 100; rw[i] = 139;

                break;

            case 'L':
                cv[i]= 5; rv[i]= 12; dv[i]= 150; rw[i] = 207;

                break;

            case 'X':
                cv[i]= 6; rv[i]= 18; dv[i]= 200; rw[i] = 345;

                break;

            default:
                printf("That was not a valid option :(");
            }

            printf("\n");

        }

        printf("\n1.First fit 2.Best fit 3.Worst fit\n");
        do
        {
            int nc[10]={0}; int dc[10]={0};
            int mc[10]={0}; int rd[10]={0};

            int host[10] = {0};


            for (i=1; i<=m; i++)

            {

                if (i==1){
                    c[i] = 64; r[i] = 64; d[i] = 700; ff[i] = i;
                }

                if (i==2){
                    c[i] = 32; r[i] = 32; d[i] = 500; ff[i] = i;
                }

            }

            printf("\nEnter your choice:");
            scanf("%d",&ch);
            switch(ch)
            {


            case 1: printf("\nFirst Fit\n");

                printf("\n\nVirtualM_No\tPhyMac_No\n");

                for(i=1; i<=nf; i++)
                {
                    flag = 1;

                    for(j=1; j<=m; j++)
                    {
                        if(cv[i] <= c[j] && rv[i]<= r[j] && dv[i] <= d[j]){

                            printf("%-15d\t%-15d\t%\n",i,ff[j]); //printf("\n");

                            count++;


                            if(ff[j]==1 || ff[j]==2 || ff[j]==3 || ff[j]==4 || ff[j]==5 || ff[j]==6 || ff[j]==7 || ff[j]== 8|| ff[j]==9 || ff[j]==10)
                            {
                                c[j] = c[j] - cv[i];
                                r[j] = r[j] - rv[i];
                                d[j] = d[j] - dv[i];
                                nc[j] = nc[j] + cv[i];
                                mc[j] = mc[j] + rv[i];
                                dc[j]= dc[j] + dv[i];
                                rd[j]= rd[j] + rw[i];
                                host[j] = host[j]+ 1;
                            }

                            break;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            flag++;

                        }

                    }
                    if(flag > m) {
                        printf("%-15d\t%-15s\n",i,"WAIT..\n");
                        // rejectvm++;
                    }
                }

                printf("\n");
                //printf("%d , %d , %d , %d \n", nc[i], rd[i], mc[i], dc[i]);



                break;


            case 2: printf("\nBest Fit\n");
                int y1, z1, temp1,temp_r1, temp_d1;


                //placing the vms

                printf("\n\nVirtualM_No\tPhyMac_No\n");
                for(i=1; i<=nf; i++)
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    for(y1=1;y1<=m;y1++)
                    {

                        for(z1=y1;z1<=m;z1++)
                        {
                            if (c[y1] !=0 && r[y1] !=0 || d[y1] !=0)
                            {
                                if(c[y1] > c[z1] && r[y1] > r[z1] && d[y1] > d[z1])
                                {
                                    temp1 = c[y1]; temp_r1 = r[y1]; temp_d1 = d[y1];
                                    c[y1]= c[z1]; r[y1]= r[z1]; d[y1]= d[z1];
                                    c[z1]=temp1; d[z1]=temp_r1; d[z1]=temp_d1;
                                    temp1=ff[y1];
                                    ff[y1]=ff[z1];
                                    ff[z1]=temp1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for(j=1; j<=m; j++)
                    {
                        if( c[j] >= cv[i] && r[j] >= rv[i] &&  d[j] >= dv[i]){

                            printf("%-15d\t%-15d\t%\n",i,ff[j]);

                            count++;

                            if(ff[j]==1 || ff[j]==2 || ff[j]==3 || ff[j]==4 ||
                                ff[j]==5 || ff[j]==6 || ff[j]==7 || ff[j]== 8|| ff[j]==9 || ff[j]==10)
                            {
                                c[j] = c[j] - cv[i];
                                r[j] = r[j] - rv[i];
                                d[j] = d[j] - dv[i];
                                //ctr[i] = ctr[i] + 1;
                                nc[j] = nc[j] + cv[i];
                                mc[j] = mc[j] + rv[i];
                                dc[j]= dc[j] + dv[i];
                                rd[j]= rd[j] + rw[i];
                                host[j] = host[j]+ 1;
                            }

                            break;

                        }

                        else {
                            flag++;
                        }



                    }
                    if(flag > m) {
                        printf("%-15d\t%-15s\n",i,"WAIT...\n");

                    }
                }

                printf("\n");


                break;



            case 3: printf("\nWorst Fit\n");
                int y, z, temp,temp_r, temp_d;


                //placing the vms

                printf("\n\nVirtualM_No\tPhyMac_No\n");
                for(i=1; i<=nf; i++)
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    for(j=1; j<=m; j++)
                    {
                        for(y=1;y<=m;y++)
                        {
                            for(z=y;z<=m;z++)
                            {
                                if(c[y] < c[z] && r[y] < r[z] && d[y] < d[z])
                                {
                                    temp = c[y]; temp_r = r[y]; temp_d = d[y];
                                    c[y]= c[z]; r[y]= r[z]; d[y]= d[z];
                                    c[z]=temp; r[z]=temp_r; d[z]=temp_d;
                                    temp1=ff[y];
                                    ff[y]=ff[z];
                                    ff[z]=temp1;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if( c[j] >= cv[i] && r[j] >= rv[i] &&  d[j] >= dv[i]){

                            printf("%-15d\t%-15d\t%d\n",i,ff[j],j);

                            count++; g = ff[j];


                            if(ff[j]==1 || ff[j]==2 || ff[j]==3 || ff[j]==4 || ff[j]==5 || ff[j]==6 || ff[j]==7 || ff[j]== 8|| ff[j]==9 || ff[j]==10)
                            {

                                c[j] = c[j] - cv[i];
                                r[j] = r[j] - rv[i];
                                d[j] = d[j] - dv[i];
                                //  ctr[i] = ctr[i] + 1;
                                nc[g] = nc[g] + cv[i];
                                mc[g] = mc[g] + rv[i];
                                dc[g]= dc[g] + dv[i];
                                rd[g]= rd[g] + rw[i];
                                host[g] = host[g]+ 1;

                            }

                            break;


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            flag++;

                        }



                    }
                    if(flag > m) {

                        printf("%-15d\t%-15s\n",i,"WAIT...\n");

                    }
                }

                printf("\n");
                break;

            default:
                printf("That was not a valid option :(");
                break;
            }

        }

        while(ch<=3);
    }
}



int my_rand ()
{
    static int first = 0;

    if (first == 0)
    {
        srand (time (NULL));
        first = 1;
    }
    return (rand ()% 4);
}
```

Comment: `for(i=1; i<=nf; i++)` arrays are zero based in C. Valid indexes are in the range `0..N-1`

Comment: Please introduce your shortcuts (VM, PM, ...) on first usage and don't let the reader guess them from the code at the bottom.

Comment: Please the VM and PM represent Virtual Machine and Physical Machines respectively..

Comment: I have noticed the error. it is supposed to be r[z1]=temp_r1 and not d[z1]=temp_r1
Thank you all for your assistance.